# Как исправить ошибку с jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытался работать с jQuery но возникли вот эти ошибки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за чего они возникли?

Вот часть кода где я думаю есть проблема.

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function(event){
    var hashSplit = $.param.fragment().split("-");
    var hashString = "";
    for(var i=0; i<hashSplit.length-1; i++)
        hashString = hashString + hashSplit[i] + (i+1<hashSplit.length-1 ? "-" : "");
    if(hashSplit[0].substr(0,11)!="prettyPhoto")
    {
        if(hashSplit[0].substr(0,7)!="filter=")
        {
            $('.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header#accordion-' + decodeURIComponent($.param.fragment())).trigger("change");
            $('.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header#accordion-' + decodeURIComponent(hashString)).trigger("change");
        }
        $('.tabs .ui-tabs-nav [href="#' + decodeURIComponent(hashString) + '"]').trigger("change");
        $('.tabs .ui-tabs-nav [href="#' + decodeURIComponent($.param.fragment()) + '"]').trigger("change");
        if(hashSplit[0].substr(0,7)!="filter=")
            $('.tabs .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header#accordion-' + decodeURIComponent($.param.fragment())).trigger("change");
        $(".testimonials-list, .our-clients-list:not('.type-list')").trigger('configuration', ['debug', false, true]);
        $(document).scroll();
    }
    if(hashSplit[0].substr(0,7)=="comment")
    {
        if($(location.hash).length)
        {
            var offset = $(location.hash).offset();
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: offset.top-10}, 400);
        }
    }

    // get options object from hash
    var hashOptions = $.deparam.fragment();

    if(hashSplit[0].substr(0,7)=="filter")
    {
        var filterClass = decodeURIComponent($.param.fragment()).substr(7, decodeURIComponent($.param.fragment()).length);
        // apply options from hash
        $(".isotope-filters a").removeClass("selected");
        if($('.isotope-filters a[href="#filter-' + filterClass + '"]').length)
            $('.isotope-filters a[href="#filter-' + filterClass + '"]').addClass("selected");
        else
            $(".isotope-filters li:first a").addClass("selected");

        $(".isotope").isotope({filter: (filterClass!="*" ? "." : "") + filterClass});
    }
}).trigger("hashchange");

$('body.dont-scroll').on("touchmove", {}, function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Вот все подключаемые скрипты и библиотеки

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--slider revolution-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/jquery.hint.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/jquery.costCalculator.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/jquery.parallax.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/jquery.blockUI.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/googlemaps/gmap3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/js/odometer.min.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA2LLXoPbK_YPWDdpwgHaG3-PFYl6KiWhI"></script>-->


<!-- JS for local website -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/rs-plugin/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/rs-plugin/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/rs-plugin/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/rs-plugin/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/rs-plugin/js/extensions/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/rs-plugin/js/extensions/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/rs-plugin/js/extensions/revolution.extension.migration.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/glass/rs-plugin/js/extensions/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js"></script>
<!-- END of JS for local website -->
```

Так же вот блок нужный из html

```
<div class="row gray full-width page-margin-top-section page-padding-top-section padding-bottom-66">

<h2 class="box-header">ЭТАПЫ РАБОТ</h2>
<p class="description align-center">Заказывая перегородки в Queentia будут обязательные этапы работ обеспечивающие максимально быстрое и качественное выполнение заказа.</p>
<p class="description align-center"></p>


<div class="row">
    <div class="tabs no-scroll clearfix ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <ul class="tabs-navigation clearfix ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="we-offer" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true">
                <a href="index.html#we-offer" title="We Offer" class="sl-small-list ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">
                    Подбор перегородок
                </a>
                <span></span>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="we-guarantee" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">
                <a href="index.html#we-guarantee" title="We Guarantee" class="sl-small-measure ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">
                    Проведение замеров
                </a>
                <span></span>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="we-provide" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">
                <a href="index.html#we-provide" title="We Provide" class="sl-small-gears ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-4">
                    Производство
                </a>
                <span></span>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="we-provide2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">
                <a href="index.html#we-provide2" title="We Provide" class="sl-small-driller ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-5">
                    Монтаж
                </a>
                <span></span>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="we-provide3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-6" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">
                <a href="index.html#we-provide3" title="We Provide" class="sl-small-shield ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-6">
                    Гарантия
                </a>
                <span></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
                        <div id="we-offer" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">
                <h4 class="box-header">Подбор перегородок</h4>
                <p>Консультант Queentia поможет Вам выбрать наиболее подходящий для Вас вариант перегородок.</p>
            </div>
                        <div id="we-guarantee" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                <h4 class="box-header">Проведение замеров</h4>
                <p>Замерщик приедет к Вам в удобное для вас время и снимет все необходимые размеры для производства перегородок.</p>
            </div>
                        <div id="we-provide" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                <h4 class="box-header">Производство</h4>
                <p>В производственной мастерской создадут перегородки точно по вашим размерам.</p>
            </div>
                        <div id="we-provide2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                <h4 class="box-header">Монтаж</h4>
                <p>Специалисты установят перегородки в любой удобный для Вас день и даже в выходные! ЗАКАЗАТЬ РАСЧЕТ ПРОЕКТА</p>
            </div>
                        <div id="we-provide3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-6" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                <h4 class="box-header">Гарантийное обслуживание</h4>
                <p>Перегородки очень надежные и обычно с ними ничего не случается, но если вдруг что-то пойдет не так, наши мастера оперативно устранят неисправность!</p>
            </div>
                </div>
</div>
<div class="row gray full-width padding-top-54 padding-bottom-30 align-center">
    <div> <a class="more" href="index.html#calculate" title="ЗАКАЗАТЬ РАСЧЕТ ПРОЕКТА">ЗАКАЗАТЬ РАСЧЕТ ПРОЕКТА</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Из-за кривого кода например

Comment: Покажите ваш код. Кстати а почему такую старую версию jquery используете?

Comment: Вообще предположу, что используется Bootstrap или jquery-ui. И он должен использоваться с конкретной версией jquery, которая как раз не была учтена

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский да, тоже подумал что сторонняя библиотека, но тут уж совсем старая версия. Бутстрап 3.3.7 использует 2xxx версию.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин ну вот поэтому 1.11  и не вывозит. Логично же

Comment: И как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: @olishevskyalex `Вот часть кода` - а html можно? ....видно же что проблема в тут: `decodeURIComponent($.param.fragment())`/`decodeURIComponent(hashString)` - неверный селектор

Comment: `И как можно решить данную проблему?` - пока непонятно какую проблему решаем-с, ибо вы не ответили на вопрос какую библиотеку вы используете помимо jquery и какую версию...... ну и html нужно посмотреть

Comment: Вот информация о библиотеках и всех скриптах

Comment: кстати substring можно делать просто "hallow".substring(2), это будет сразу до конца строки работать и не надо будет вычислять длинну строки.

Comment: Не знал об этом, но это же не из-за этого ошибка с синтаксисом... Я бы хотел разобраться из-за чего она тут вылезла.

Comment: в приведенном html нет `ui-accordion-header`